# Add a new line to a text file in MS-DOS

Tags: batch-file, newline

I am making a `.bat` file, and I would like it to write [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) into a text file.

I was able to find the command to append a new line to the file when echoing text, but when I read that text file, all I see is a layout-sign and not a space. I think it would work by opening that file with Word or even [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad), but I would like it to work on any computer, even if that computer only has [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) (which is mostly the case).

How can I open the text file in a certain program (i.e. WordPad) or write a proper space character to the file?

---

**EDIT:**

I found that it is the best way to use:

```
echo <line1> > <filename>
echo <line2> >> <filename>
```

P.S. I used `|` in my ASCII art, so it crashed, Dumb Dumb Dumb :)

Comment: I'm afraid the question needs serious reformulation and a few input/output/code samples. You've lost ma about half way through...

Comment: wow, you're everywhere.  Its hard to understand what you're asking.  Try to ask a clear question in as few lines as possible.  Also, a sample containing what you are doing now would help.

Comment: "Tough when it writes to a txt file i just see a layout-sign not a space"  That hurt my head.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
echo Hello, > file.txt
echo.       >>file.txt
echo world  >>file.txt
```

and you can always run:

```
wordpad file.txt
```

on any version of Windows.

---

On Windows 2000 and above you can do:

```
( echo Hello, & echo. & echo world ) > file.txt
```

---

Another way of showing a message for a small amount of text is to create file.vbs containing:

```
Msgbox "Hello," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "world", 0, "Message"
```

Call it with

```
cscript /nologo file.vbs
```

Or use `wscript` if you don't need it to wait until they click OK.

---

The problem with the message you're writing is that the vertical bar (`|`) is the ["pipe" operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(character)#DOS.2FWindows).  You'll need to escape it by using `^|` instead of `|`.

*P.S. it's spelled [Pwned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwn)*.

Comment: Ty!
I didn't realise that that adds a line!
Awesome :)

Comment: yeah i noticed that i could do that but im trying to keep it compact you see, just create the file, else it would just copy it :)
But theres no way to do that with only using write 1 time now is there?

Comment: There should be a **bold warning** saying that `>` overwrites entire file content :)

Answer (score 13):

You can easily append to the end of a file, by using the redirection char twice (`>>`).

---

This will copy `source.txt` to `destination.txt`, overwriting destination in the process:

```
type source.txt > destination.txt
```

This will copy `source.txt` to `destination.txt`, appending to destination in the process:

```
type source.txt >> destination.txt
```

Comment: indeed tough, i just want it to create the file, not copy..<br>
else i could just make it open a file withotu creating it first, but i think its better to have it as compact as posible.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
echo foo > test.txt
echo. >> test.txt
echo bar >> test.txt
```

results in the following within test.txt:

> foo
>
> bar

Comment: yeah i think it would be the best way to do this, i might edit the file to make a command that will split it up in parts...<br>
at least, ill try ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "text to echo" > file.txt
```

Comment: that would just (optonally)create a command, write a line on it.. but it wouldnt make a next line ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
echo (text here) >> (name here).txt
```

Ex. `echo my name is jeff >> test.txt`

test.txt

```
my name is jeff
```

You can use it in a script too.

Answer (score 1):

- I always use `copy con`  to write text, It so easy to write a long text
- Example:

  > C:\COPY CON [drive:][path][File name]
  >
  > .... Content
  >
  > F6
  >
  > 1 file(s) is copied