# Append text at the end of all files in a directory

Tags: windows, cmd, notepad++

I have a directory with over 100 text files.

How can I append the word "END" at the end of every file within that directory?

Comment: Do you want to rename every file  in a directory?. or add END inside the file?

Comment: That is not a job for NOtepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language. Try something and come back if you have some difficulties.

Comment: I don't need to rename anything, just add "END" inside every file.

Comment: @Toto I was hoping that there was a special character that would match the end of a file, then it could work if we did a replace of that character on every file of that folder.

Comment: `Find what: \z` & `Replace with: END` does the job for 1 file (`\z` means end of file). To modify 100+ files you can do that 100+ times or, simpler, write a script.

Comment: @Toto Works like a charm! You can do it for 100 files in the blink of an eye by using the "Replace in Files" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. Backup your files.
2. Go to the relevant directory.
3. [Open CMD from that directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10135218/6327676)
4. Run this command.

`for %f in (*.txt) do echo END >> %f`

[image: Screenshot]

Note:
If your text file encoding is not `ANSI`, then the result might be different from what you want.

```
ANSI > This is a test.END
Unicode > This is a test.久⁄਍
Unicode big endian > This is a test.䕎䐠ഊ
UTF-8 > This is a test.END
```

---

<sup>You might want to check these links too...</sup>

- <sup>[Add a new line to a text file in MS-DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/773610/6327676)</sup>
- <sup>[How to do something to each file in a directory with a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180741/6327676)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell option:

```
 "END" | Add-Content -path *.txt
```

`Add-Content` will append the pipeline input to all files matching its parameters (there are other options to include/exclude lists of wildcard patterns).